# Someone has written 100 thousand (!) answers (graphic design bug)

Tags: bug, design, user-profile-page, statistics, typography

I was really surprised to see that [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) has written 100570 answers!

[image]

I thought it's a bit too much, and indeed -- it is. The number of answers blends into the number of questions. In my opinion, this is at least non- aesthetic.

Comment: I would be more surprised if it would be the other way round :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You mean 10.0 answers and 570 questions? ;-)

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer: Nooooooooooooooooooo! 0 answers and 10057 questions :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, but my figures make more sense considering ... oh, never mind ;-)

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer: You mean 10.0? ;-) I noticed the decimal point :-P And I do mind :-(((((

Comment: Twelve million people reached. Oh my.

Comment: @PauloCereda I wonder how many of the 12 million are the dozen people that regularly visit the chat :D I suppose at least a million :-)

Comment: @yo' oooh! `:)`

Comment: What a blasphemy! How dare you visit egreg's profile? His stats are basically numbers coming out of integer overflows. It can very well be 3 instead.

Comment: For reference, [this/Meta.TeX.SE seems to be the appropriate place for posting this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3802460#3802460), is different sites have different fonts, making the problem (perhaps) specific to [tex.se].

Comment: This post is getting upvotes! -so it must be just me, but: *I do not see any question.*

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen You don't see that there is **no padding** between the number of answers and the number of questions?

Comment: @yo': Yes - I see that. I still do not see that your post on this question and answer page actually contain any question!

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen No question here, no answer. Just a bug report. Maybe you should learn how meta works?

Comment: Aside from the change over time (the count now having climbed from 10,057 to 12,467), it appears to me to indicate (whether accurately or not) multi-thousands of answers and 0 questions.